# "trigger insert after" to insert data from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

here i have table like this

destination:

```
  |id_dest | price |
  |     1  |2000   |
  |     2  |100    |
  |     3  |1000   |
```

item:

```
   |id_item | weight | id_dest |total(weight*destination.price) |
   |      1 |     3  |      2  |
```

the trigger should make

```
   |id_item | weight | id_dest |sum(weight*destination.price) total |
   |      1 |     3  |      2  |300
```

how the query trigger should be?

Comment: Why don't you use a generated column? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: A generated column will not work, because only columns from the same row can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
    BEFORE INSERT ON item
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE item
    SET total = (SELECT d.price *, NEW.weight 
                 FROM destination d 
                 WHERE d.id_dest = NEW.id_dest)
    WHERE id_item = NEW.id_item; 
END
```

Comment: You cannot `UPDATE` the table on wich you define the trigger. But there is no need for that. There is also no need for a JOIN. It could be just `SET NEW.total = SELECT d.price * NEW.weight FROM destination d WHERE d.id_dest = NEW.id_dest;`. But you can only do that in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: And as I wrote in my comment to the question: You cannot use data from another table for a generated column.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel OK thanks, I've updated my answer considering your insights